# Tf-agent Actor/Learner: TFUniform ReplayBuffer dimensionality issue - invalid shape of Replay Buffer vs. Actor update

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, dqn, tf-agent

I try to adapt the this [tf-agents actor<->learner](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/blob/635af30a6365ec963823d4623f14df25fcefaadd/tf_agents/experimental/examples/dqn/mnih15/dqn_train_eval_atari.py) DQN Atari Pong example to my windows machine using a [TFUniformReplayBuffer](https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/api_docs/python/tf_agents/replay_buffers/TFUniformReplayBuffer) instead of the [ReverbReplayBuffer](https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/api_docs/python/tf_agents/replay_buffers/ReverbReplayBuffer) which only works on linux machine but I face a dimensional issue.

```
    [...]
    ---> 67 init_buffer_actor.run()
    [...]
    InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__ResourceScatterUpdate_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Must have updates.shape = indices.shape + params.shape[1:] or updates.shape = [], got updates.shape [84,84,4], indices.shape [1], params.shape [1000,84,84,4] [Op:ResourceScatterUpdate]
```

The problem is as follows: The tf actor tries to access the replay buffer and initialize the it with a certain number random samples of shape (84,84,4) according to this [deepmind paper](https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/MnihEtAlHassibis15NatureControlDeepRL.pdf) but the replay buffer requires samples of shape (1,84,84,4).

My code is as follows:

```
    def train_pong(
        env_name='ALE/Pong-v5',
        initial_collect_steps=50000,
        max_episode_frames_collect=50000,
        batch_size=32,
        learning_rate=0.00025,
        replay_capacity=1000):
  
        # load atari environment
        collect_env = suite_atari.load(
            env_name,
            max_episode_steps=max_episode_frames_collect,
            gym_env_wrappers=suite_atari.DEFAULT_ATARI_GYM_WRAPPERS_WITH_STACKING)

        # create tensor specs
        observation_tensor_spec, action_tensor_spec, time_step_tensor_spec = (
            spec_utils.get_tensor_specs(collect_env))
  
        # create training util
        train_step = train_utils.create_train_step()
  
        # calculate no. of actions
        num_actions = action_tensor_spec.maximum - action_tensor_spec.minimum + 1
  
        # create agent
        agent = dqn_agent.DqnAgent(
            time_step_tensor_spec,
            action_tensor_spec,
            q_network=create_DL_q_network(num_actions),
            optimizer=tf.compat.v1.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate))
    
        # create uniform replay buffer
        replay_buffer = tf_uniform_replay_buffer.TFUniformReplayBuffer(
            data_spec=agent.collect_data_spec,
            batch_size=1,
            max_length=replay_capacity)

        # observer of replay buffer
        rb_observer = replay_buffer.add_batch
        
        # create batch dataset
        dataset = replay_buffer.as_dataset(
            sample_batch_size=batch_size,
            num_steps = 2,
            single_deterministic_pass=False).prefetch(3)
    
        # create callable function for actor
        experience_dataset_fn = lambda: dataset
  
        # create random policy for buffer init
        random_policy = random_py_policy.RandomPyPolicy(collect_env.time_step_spec(),
                                                  collect_env.action_spec())
  
        # create initalizer
        init_buffer_actor = actor.Actor(
            collect_env,
            random_policy,
            train_step,
            steps_per_run=initial_collect_steps,
            observers=[replay_buffer.add_batch])

        # initialize buffer with random samples
        init_buffer_actor.run()
```

(The approach is using the OpenAI Gym Env as well as the corresponding wrapper functions)

I worked with *keras-rl2* and *tf-agents without actor<->learner* for other atari games to create the DQN and both worked quite well afer a some adaptions. I guess my current code will also work after a few adaptions in the tf-agent libary functions, but that would obviate the purpose of the libary.

My current assumption: **The actor<->learner methods are not able to work with the TFUniformReplayBuffer  (as I expect them to), due to the missing support of the TFPyEnvironment** - or I still have some knowledge shortcomings regarding this tf-agents approach

Previous (successful) attempt:

```
    from tf_agents.environments.tf_py_environment import TFPyEnvironment
    tf_collect_env = TFPyEnvironment(collect_env)
    init_driver = DynamicStepDriver(
        tf_collect_env,
        random_policy,
        observers=[replay_buffer.add_batch],
        num_steps=200) 
     init_driver.run()
```

I would be very grateful if someone could explain me what I'm overseeing here.

Comment: It is an environment wrapper, they update output parameters I have the same problem then I use the gym.action wrapper and nother wrapper.

Comment: observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action) and
observation, reward, done, priority, info = env.step(action)

Comment: Thx, for you suggestion. I already faced your issue many times and this was the first thing that I checked.

My current assumption is that maybe I used the wrong Buffer. Because the Env. was created as an Py Env and the Buffer is TF based.
-> py_uniform_replay_buffer.PyUniformReplayBuffer instead of tf_uniform_replay_buffer.TFUniformReplayBuffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the full fix is shown below...

--> The dimensionality issue was valid and should indicate the the (uploaded) batched samples are not in the correct shape

--> This issue happens due to the fact that the "add_batch" method loads values with the wrong shape

```
    rb_observer = replay_buffer.add_batch
```

Long story short, this line should be replaced by

```
  rb_observer = lambda x: replay_buffer.add_batch(batch_nested_array(x))
```

--> Afterwards the (replay buffer) inputs are of correct shape and the Learner Actor Setup starts training.

The full replay buffer is shown below:

```
  # create buffer for storing experience
  replay_buffer = tf_uniform_replay_buffer.TFUniformReplayBuffer(
    agent.collect_data_spec,
    1,
    max_length=1000000)

 # create batch dataset
  dataset = replay_buffer.as_dataset( 
      sample_batch_size=32,
      num_steps = 2,
      single_deterministic_pass=False).prefetch(4)

  # create batched nested array input for rb_observer
  rb_observer = lambda x: replay_buffer.add_batch(batch_nested_array(x))

  # create batched readout of dataset
  experience_dataset_fn = lambda: dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it...partly, but the next error is (in my opinion) an architectural problem.

The problem is that the Actor/Learner setup is build on a PyEnvironment whereas the
TFUniformReplayBuffer is using the TFPyEnvironment which ends up in the failure above...

Using the PyUniformReplayBuffer with a converted py-spec solved this problem.

```
    from tf_agents.specs import tensor_spec
    
    # convert agent spec to py-data-spec 
    py_collect_data_spec = tensor_spec.to_array_spec(agent.collect_data_spec)
    
    # create replay buffer based on the py-data-spec
    replay_buffer = py_uniform_replay_buffer.PyUniformReplayBuffer(
        data_spec= py_collect_data_spec,
        capacity=replay_capacity*batch_size
        )
```

This snippet solved the issue of having an incompatible buffer in the background but ends up in another issue
--> The add_batch function does not work

I found [this approach](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/issues/198) which advises to use either a batched environment or to make the following adaptions for the replay observer (add_batch method).

```
  from tf_agents.utils.nest_utils import batch_nested_array
  
  #********* Adpations add_batch method - START  *********#
  rb_observer = lambda x: replay_buffer.add_batch(batch_nested_array(x))
  #********* Adpations add_batch method - END    *********#

  # create batch dataset
  dataset = replay_buffer.as_dataset( 
      sample_batch_size=32,
      single_deterministic_pass=False)
  
  experience_dataset_fn = lambda: dataset
```

This helped me to solve the issue regarding this post but now I run into another problem where I need to ask someone of the tf-agents-team...

--> It seems that the Learner/Actor structure is no able to work with another buffer than the ReverbBuffer, because the data-spec which is processed by the PyUniformReplayBuffer sets up a wrong buffer structure...

For anyone who has the same problem: I just created [this Github-Issue report](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/issues/797) to get further answers and/or fix my lack of knowledge.